# Where is HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2?

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I downloaded jetty-all (9.3.6) from maven central, however, the class HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2 doesn't exist at all. However, in the jetty docs, it says that it should be there (same version, same release date).

So where is HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2?

Comment: Why was my question down voted? jetty all should contain everything it needs. Hence the name "jetty all"

Comment: [jetty-all does not, and cannot, contain all of jetty](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html).  It is also 100% inappropriate to use as a dependency in any build.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Didn't know about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working with this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
    <artifactId>http2-http-client-transport</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.RC0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code snippet:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2 clientTransportOverHTTP2;
```

**Update 1:**

Regarding the useful comments. Version 9.3.7 is not a stable release version at the moment.

For all who wants to use a stable version this dependency should do it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
    <artifactId>http2-http-client-transport</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do not use jetty-all as a dependency in your build, use the individual dependencies instead.

Comment: @Patrick `9.3.7.RC0` is not a stable release, would recommend using `9.3.6.v20151106` (or wait until the official stable release of 9.3.7 hits)